# Ajax запрос на сторонний сервер

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Этот пример работает

```
  $.getJSON("//ulogin.ru/token.php?host=" +
                    encodeURIComponent(location.toString()) + "&token=" + this.token + "&callback=?",
                    function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        data = $.parseJSON(data.toString());
                        if (!data.error) {
                            alert("Привет, " + data.first_name + " " + data.last_name + "!");
                        }
                    });
```

Так не работает

```
 $http.get(url).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data);

                        this.busy = false;
                        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                            callback();
                        }
                    }.bind(this)).
                    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    });
```

Как отправить такой же запрос angular как в рабочем примере на jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var url = "//ulogin.ru/token.php?host=" +
                    encodeURIComponent(location.toString()) + "&token=" + this.token + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
```

вся суть callback=JSON_CALLBACK

```
$http.jsonp(url).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data);

                        this.busy = false;
                        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                            callback();
                        }
                    }.bind(this)).
                    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    });
```